# Selector by name, in box with my class name jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, attributes

How to specify to take all values from inputs by input name, only in certain class ?

For example if I tried to take value from all inputs with name 'album_id', I have set

```
$("input[name='album_id']").val()
```

and it works, but if I want to show that take all inputs, which only in box with class 'photo' and I tried to write

```
$(".photo").find("input[name='album_id']").val()
```

or

```
$(".photo > input[name='album_id']").val()
```

and this construction does not work. But by the way when I take all classes with name 'foo' from block with class 'foo_wrapper' and I set

```
$('.addPhoto_wrapper').find('.alb_btn')
```

and it's work correctly.

So why dont work same construction?

Fiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/V2e3r/

Comment: Can you show your HTML and create a fiddle?

Comment: I tried with same case and it is working at my side... can you pls share JSfiddle for this

Comment: Yeah, no problem, one moment please. :)

Comment: are you able to make JSFiddle .. if not you can post html structure you are using

Comment: after looking at JSfiddle ... i dont find any div with class="addPhoto" ...

Comment: `$(".addPhoto_wrapper").find("input[name='album_id']")` works fine.

Comment: Oooohhh.... i'm stupid idiot. I just misprint with class name, i'm sorry. Thanks for helping. :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you query all the inputs and its selector. Lets say the code is as follows:

```
<div class="photo">
   <input type="text" name='album_id' value="1"/>
   <input type="text" name='album_id' value="2"/>
   <input type="text" name='album_id' value="3"/>
</div>
<input type="text" name='album_id' value="4"/>
```

Then the way to select those inputs would be like this:

```
var inputCollection = $('.photo input[name="album_id"]');
$.each(inputCollection, function(key, value){
    console.log(value);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a7LqP/
I hope its a start for you.

Edit: I forgot to mention - while looping through all the inputs in collection, referring to $(this) instead of **value** will return jQuery object of the current input.

Comment: Thanks, but not, i dont have, and dont need many inputs with name 'album_id', i understand that array i need get in loop. 
I have only one input with name 'album_id', and on click button with class `.alb_btn` i need to set new value for this input with name `album_id`, from data attr from clicked button. And problem in selector, that i want strictly showed that change value need only to input with name `album_id` ONLY which in class '.photo' for example.

Comment: and problem just in selector, that just i not correctly set it.
For example with that construction `var test_val = $("input[name='album_id']").val();` all work, with that dont work `var test_val = $(".addPhoto").find("input[name='album_id']").val();`

But if i just left firsth example, without strictly showed from which class i need get value by name, in future i get problems with multiply inputs with name album_id

Answer (score 0):

Use as below:

```
  var inputCollection = $('.photo').find($('input[name="album_id"]'));
  $.each(inputCollection, function(key, value){
    console.log(value);
  });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LW6k8/)